# Evaluate: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^{n}(x)\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x^2)}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, closed-form

Looking for the closed form of this integral

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^{n}(x)\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x^2)}\mathrm dx=G(n)$$

$n:=1,3,5,7,...$

Wolfram can evaluate it but I can't generalise into a closed form.

Can anyone help, please.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^{3}(x)\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x^2)}\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{256}[-24\pi^2\zeta(3)-45\zeta(5)-7\pi^4\ln(4)]$$

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source and motivation of the problem, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: E.g. it can make sense to start with $x:=\tan t$ .